# error with detecting canvas ui object on touchphase.ended

Tags: android, user-interface, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Unity just implemented in version 4.6 the new ui canvas. its great and all but I'm trying to detect a coordinate of the screen and check if a canvas ui object is visible in that pixel. so to do this I have attempted many methods of achieving it but the only two methods which came close were these.

```
if(EventSystems.EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId)){
```

shouldLatchFinger = false;
}

the problem with the above code is that it searches by finger id which is nice but when you press your finger when the finger is released it will go to the function i have and since the touch.phase == ended  ispointerovergameobject will return false despite my function still needing this to return true due to the location still factually being over a canvas ui object you would think that it would allow me to input a coordinate system but it seems there is no overload for a screen coordinate

ie:

```
void update()
{
    switch (touch.touchphase)
    {
            case touchphase.began: 
            shouldLatchFinger = false;
            if(EventSystems.EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId)){
                 shouldLatchFinger = false;
            }
            break;
            case touchphase.ended: 
            shouldLatchFinger = false;
            if(EventSystems.EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId)){
                 shouldLatchFinger = false;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

so despite my desire to use that code i opted for this other method

working c# implementation

```
 if(EventSystem.current != null){
                PointerEventData pointer = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);

                pointer.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(hit.point);

                List<RaycastResult> raycastResults = new List<RaycastResult>();

                EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointer, raycastResults);


                if(raycastResults.Count>0){
                    return;
                }
                }
```

This method works perfect as I desire however I need to re-implement it in JavaScript as well in my attempts to do so I found the unity api documentation on their new ui from 4.6 rather lacking and inaccurate.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.RaycastAll.html
if you switch between java and c# on that page unity is apparently saying that the list class exists in javascript as well am i missing something or can someone help me finish converting this to js.

my attempt to convert to JS

```
shouldLatchFinger = true;
if(EventSystems.EventSystem.current != null){

var pointer : EventSystems.PointerEventData = new EventSystems.PointerEventData (EventSystems.EventSystem.current);

pointer.position = touch.position;

var raycastResults ;// List(RaycastHit);// = new List(RaycastHit);

EventSystems.EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointer, raycastResults);


if(raycastResults != null){
shouldLatchFinger=false;
}
}
}
```

this gives an error in logcat of this however

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
I/Unity   ( 4109):   at UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.RaycastAll (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 raycastResults) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent\work\XXXXXXXXXXXXX\Extensions\guisystem\guisystem\EventSystem\EventSystem.cs:158
I/Unity   ( 4109):   at xxxxx.Update () [0x000e6] in Z:\Documents\Projects\XXXXXXXXXX\Assets\Standard Assets\Scripts\xxxxx.js:159
I/Unity   ( 4109):
I/Unity   ( 4109): (Filename: C Line: 0)
```

if i am not mistaken its due to the fact that

```
" at UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.RaycastAll (PointerEventData eventData, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 raycastResults)"
```

as seen here makes ref to system.collections.generic.list but the issue here is that my raycastresults list is a var or object and when the eventsystem.raycastall tries to access it its referencing a null object which since its more likely trying to access the method Add to populate the array but its inaccessible since its not initialized yet. so i guess the overall question is how to i instantiate a list in javascript for unity.

Comment: I'm sure the answer is simple and im just too stupid to see it.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
import System.Collections.Generic;

function TestMethod () 
{
    var raycastResults = new List.<RaycastHit>();
}
```